# Translate selection fields from another model - Template Website Odoo 11

Tags: templates, odoo

I have a selection type field  who is coming another model. But, my traduction file do not take it into account. I am looking to find a other solution for translate values fields this select field.

Any idea ?

EDIT :

**Here my template code :**

```
                ...<table class="table table-hover table_requests" id="order_tableau">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Reference</th>
                            <th scope="col">Type</th>
                            <th scope="col">Applicant</th>
                            <th scope="col">Date</th>
                            <th scope="col">State</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <t t-foreach="requests_grc" t-as="request_grc">
                            <tr id="result_requests" t-att-onclick="'window.location=\'/web#id='+str(request_grc.id)+'&amp;view_type=form&amp;model=website.application&amp;menu_id=299&amp;action=389\''"
                                t-att-class="'cursor-pointer'">
                                <td><t t-esc="request_grc.name"/></td>
                                <td><t t-esc="request_grc.website_application_template_id.name"/></td>
                                <td><t t-esc="request_grc.applicant_id.name"/></td>
                                <td><t t-esc="request_grc.date" t-options="{'widget': 'date'}"/></td>
                                <td><t t-esc="request_grc.state"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </t>
                    </tbody>
                </table>...
```

**Here my Python code :**

```
requests_grc = http.request.env['website.application'].search([])
```

**Result**

[image]

I would translate the last element on my table : ***request_grc.state***

EDIT :

```
@http.route('/web_demarches/', auth='user', website=True)
def indexDemarches(self, **kw):

    user = http.request.env.user.name
    active_new = False
    active_in_progress = False
    active_completed_request = False
    active_refused_request = False
    nb_new_request = 0
    nb_in_progress_request = 0
    nb_completed_request = 0
    nb_refused_request = 0
    requests_grc = http.request.env['website.application'].search([])
    requests_grc_new = http.request.env['website.application'].search([('state', '=', 'new')])
    requests_grc_in_progress = http.request.env['website.application'].search(['|', ('state', '=', 'in_progress'),
                                                                                    ('state', '=', 'is_pending')])
    requests_grc_completed = http.request.env['website.application'].search([('state', '=', 'completed')])
    requests_grc_refused = http.request.env['website.application'].search([('state', '=', 'rejected')])

    for request_new in requests_grc_new:
        nb_new_request = nb_new_request + 1

    for request_in_progress in requests_grc_in_progress:
        nb_in_progress_request = nb_in_progress_request + 1

    for request_completed in requests_grc_completed:
        nb_completed_request = nb_completed_request + 1

    for request_refused in requests_grc_refused:
        nb_refused_request = nb_refused_request + 1

    return http.request.render('grc_parthenay.demarches', {
        'user': user,
        'active_new': active_new,
        'active_in_progress': active_in_progress,
        'active_completed_request': active_completed_request,
        'active_refused_request': active_refused_request,
        'requests_grc': requests_grc,
        'requests_grc_new': requests_grc_new,
        'requests_grc_in_progress': requests_grc_in_progress,
        'requests_grc_completed': requests_grc_completed,
        'requests_grc_refused': requests_grc_refused,
        'nb_new_request': nb_new_request,
        'nb_in_progress_request': nb_in_progress_request,
        'nb_completed_request': nb_completed_request,
        'nb_refused_request': nb_refused_request,
    })
```

Comment: Could you please add your code?

Comment: Yes ! I have edit my question

Comment: The python code is missing, that should be the more important code to look at ;-)

Comment: it's good, it's a controllers. Thanks